# Centered text 2nd line pushed over

Tags: css

on my website I have a content box in the middle, and I have two lines of centered text. The second one seems to be pushed over, despite the centered tags. I have highlighted the text in this image:
[image: image 1]

My code is as follows:

```
<div id="welcomeText">
                <center>
                    <h2>Bitcoin payments made easy.</h2>
                    <h3>Our services make it easier
                    <br>to start accepting Bitcoin.</h3>
                </center>
            </div>
```

My CSS is as follows:

```
#welcomeText {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#welcomeText h2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "PT Sans";
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 35px;
}
#welcomeText h3 {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "PT Sans";
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

I need to figure out how to completely center it.

Thank you.

EDIT:
I fixed the problem by making it an inline-block and floating it left, I think it was conflicting with my navbar. Thank you to all that helped.

Comment: This code seems to execute fine. Is there something else you do somewhere?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/twam8ztw/

Comment: This is not complete CSS, i guess? This works just fine, even with deprecated center tag...

Comment: Thats very weird... When the window on mine is small it's centered, but when it's stretched out its wrong like the screenshot.